# Deserialize Big JSON Array and extracting data from it

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

Currently i'am working on a project that use Azure Media Indexing services (extract text from video etc..). After indexing i get the response result as json. With this website (http://json2csharp.com/) i have created the view model for my project. I want to extract certain data from this json. Now the problem is when i try to parse the json, the system is stuck on the deserializing line.

Basically i tried to deserialize like below,

```
IList<IndexedVideoReponseVM> modelObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<IndexedVideoReponseVM>>(responseData);
```

I have tried almost all the code snippets available in stackoverflow like javascript serializer, JSON.net etc... I think maybe its because of the size of the json. I have uploaded the sample json to here (http://myjson.com/1g74kx) and here is my VM (http://textuploader.com/d6218). Could some one please analyze this and let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON at your link is not an array, it is a single element. On top of that you wrapped all generated classes including class `RootObject` in your `IndexedVideoReponseVM` class, but that is not the right approach.

Please remove the wrapping class `IndexedVideoReponseVM` (keep all that is inside), and then deserialize the JSON like this: **`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseData)`**.

Of course once that works you can give `RootObject` a more fitting name (json2sharp could not do that because it has no information about the outer object).

Comment: that came across my mind and tried it. but i couldn't find how to extract data from the resultant object(see this https://ibb.co/daB1KF).

Comment: @KRIZTE all your JSON string should be in one big square brackets to be considered as a list.

Comment: @Abdullah, are you suggesting i should do something like this ??IndexedVideoReponseVM modelObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IndexedVideoReponseVM>("[" + responseData + "]"); still no luck..

Comment: @KRIZTE yes but with the list object IList<IndexedVideoReponseVM> .

Comment: Please see my updated answer, based on your question update.

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned and the VS just freeze up when debugger come over that line. Weird! Like nothing is happening (or) is it deserialize job is going on due to large json data??

Comment: Tested all code myself, it deserializes fine here in < 0.5 sec, using the latest Newtonsoft.Json (10.0.x).

Answer (score 0):

I think it has do to something with your JSON being double quotationed. I had a similar issue a while back, i tried deserializing it after processed through [escaper](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output) and it worked for me :) You should escape the received JSON first or replace a double quotes if u can.

Comment: Is this what you mean?
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IndexedVideoReponseVM>(responseData.Replace(""","\""))

Comment: Backspace is replaced with \b
Newline is replaced with \n
Tab is replaced with \t
Carriage return is replaced with \r
Form feed is replaced with \f
Double quote is replaced with \"
Backslash is replaced with \\

By the way, why are your classes defined like this? In your class i only see nested class declarations. Nothing like defining a property. Am i not aware of some new method to define classes and properties in a combined way?

Comment: My solution might be wrong because i just saw that its an empty object that is serialized. Not a proper one, it doesn't have any properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IndexedVideoReponseVM.RootObject>(str);
```

this code executes at 435 ms (less then 1 second)

full code example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            var str = @"{
  ""accountId"": ""496c-aed1-ab750d882fa5"",
  ""id"": ""acd8121234"",

//i've cut most part of text couse of stackoverflow.com limitation on 30000 symbols. Code was tested with full json

  ""social"": {
    ""likedByUser"": false,
    ""likes"": 0,
    ""views"": 0
  }
}";

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IndexedVideoReponseVM.RootObject>(str);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Deserialized at {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms ({sw.ElapsedTicks} tiks)");
        }
    }
}
```